# Wrong drop from the reaper?

Tags: persona-4-golden

I'm farming the Reaper on a first playthrough (not NG+), and I've already got the MC's weapon, Yosuke's weapon, Teddie's weapon, Yukiko's weapon, Chie's weapon, and Kanji's weapon. With Yosuke, Teddie, and Yukiko in my part, I farmed four sets of Gold Robes, then switched my party to Chie, Kanji, and Naoto to farm their weapons. However, the third time I killed him with this party, instead of dropping Naoto's weapon, he dropped a Gold Robe! Naoto has the Magatsu Kiba equipped, and the internet says the reaper weapon is the Black Hole. What am I doing wrong? Why didn't a Black Hole drop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this thread on gamefaqs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/641695-persona-4-golden/65188234), it appears that the reaper weapons simply have a higher chance of dropping than the robe or the orb do.

> The weapons have a higher chance (if the corresponding party member is in your current party) than the armor dropping, but this chance is just that: a chance. I had a full party of everyone with their reaper weapons except Yukiko. When I beat the reaper, I got a Godly Robe instead of her fan. Her fan dropped on the next reaper encounter. Keep at it. The weapons will drop so long as that member is in your battle party.

So basically, you got (un)lucky and might have more luck the next time you kill the reaper.

Comment: as it happens, I reloaded my save and got Black Hole next time. So this looks like the right answer. Thanks!